# Currently in my App is opening multiple cell while tapping ,How can i Expand only “one” cell at a time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to expand tableview cell on it's click. in my tableview, which is  two or more cells are expandable. but I would like make, when i click on expandable cell it should show cells under it and on clicking again it should hide.it means tapping on a cell, the cell should be expanded only one other cell should be Collapse

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

    UITableView *mTableView;
    NSMutableArray *sectionTitleArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *sectionContentDict;
    NSMutableArray      *arrayForBool;
    NSInteger previousSelectedIndex;

}


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    mTableView.delegate = self;
    mTableView.dataSource = self;
    mTableView.rowHeight = 70;
    [self.view addSubview:mTableView];


    if (!sectionTitleArray) {
        sectionTitleArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Aachen", @"Berlin", @"Düren", @"Essen", @"Münster", nil];
    }
    if (!arrayForBool) {
        arrayForBool    = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] , nil];
    }
    if (!sectionContentDict) {
        sectionContentDict  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSArray *array1     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bla 1", @"bla 2", @"bla 3", @"bla 4", nil];
        [sectionContentDict setValue:array1 forKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSArray *array2     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wurst 1", @"käse 2", @"keks 3", nil];
        [sectionContentDict setValue:array2 forKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        NSArray *array3     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"banane", @"auto2", @"haus", @"eidechse", nil];
        [sectionContentDict setValue:array3 forKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:2]];
        NSArray *array4     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hoden", @"pute", @"eimer", @"wichtel", @"karl", @"dreirad", nil];
        [sectionContentDict setValue:array4 forKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:3]];
        NSArray *array5     = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ei", @"kanone", nil];
        [sectionContentDict setValue:array5 forKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:4]];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
#pragma mark - Table View
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [sectionTitleArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue]) {
        return [[sectionContentDict valueForKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]] count];
    }
    return 1;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *headerView              = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    headerView.tag                  = section;
    headerView.backgroundColor      = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UILabel *headerString           = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-20-50, 50)];
    BOOL manyCells                  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue];
    if (!manyCells) {
        headerString.text = @"click to enlarge";
    }else{
        headerString.text = @"click again to reduce";
    }
    headerString.textAlignment      = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    headerString.textColor          = [UIColor blackColor];
    [headerView addSubview:headerString];

    UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
    [headerView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

    //up or down arrow depending on the bool
    UIImageView *upDownArrow        = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:manyCells ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"upArrowBlack"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"downArrowBlack"]];
    upDownArrow.autoresizingMask    = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    upDownArrow.frame               = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-40, 10, 30, 30);
    [headerView addSubview:upDownArrow];

    return headerView;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    UIView *footer  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    return footer;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 50;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]) {
        return 50;
    }
    return 1;
}
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }
    BOOL manyCells  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
    if (!manyCells) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"click to enlarge";
    }
    else{
        NSArray *content = [sectionContentDict valueForKey:[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
#pragma mark - gesture tapped
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];


    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
        collapsed       = !collapsed;
        [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:collapsed]];

        //reload specific section animated

        NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
        NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
        [mTableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    previousSelectedIndex = indexPath.section;

}
```

Please help me, where i am going wrong

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to do, your title and description is contradicting.

Comment: hi i would like to open only one cell at time and other cell should be Collapse while tapping on a cell

Comment: then how other cells would be appearing?

Comment: all cell is appearing expanded

Comment: Please see my answer below and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: @GurtejSingh's answer has a perfect approach for this, you may use header as a cell and on header click show sections of that header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming you want to expand only one section at a time, and close other headers if open. Update your question if my understanding is correct.

In your code, you are only setting the value in the arrayForBool to 1 for which section you expand. What about the previously expanded section? You need to set that to 0.

You had no code to collapse the previously expanded section. Try the code below and let me know if it works:

```
- (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];

    [mTableView beginUpdates];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        BOOL collapsed  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];
        collapsed       = !collapsed;
        [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:collapsed]];
        if (previousSelectedIndex != indexPath.section)
        {
            [mTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:previousSelectedIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [arrayForBool replaceObjectAtIndex:previousSelectedIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:0]];
        }

        //reload specific section animated

        NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
        NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
        [mTableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    previousSelectedIndex = indexPath.section;
    [mTableView endUpdates];

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you update your question and your title and put relevant requirements there.